# Change the order during bundling in web essentials

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

I am trying to bundle files using web essentials

I installed the web essentials and added it to the extensions

I selected the files to minify as in the below image

http://blogs.msdn.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/550x0/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-15-70/3223.5.JPG

But i couldnt find any option to set the order in which the files should be bundled, for example, in the image, i want to move knockoutvalidation.js to the top and have jQuery.js after that in the bundled file

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, here goes -- my first post on StackOverflow! Gulp.

Web Essentials should have created a `.bundle` file containing XML used for configuration. Use the `files` node to change the order; eg, here `foo.js` is bundled before `bar.js`:

```
<files>
  <file>foo.js</file>
  <file>bar.js</file>
</files>
```